# how to get access to a list of items in a cell in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame in pandas including several columns, I need to get access to the one cell which contains a list of items, how would it be possible?
(e.g. how to get access to Match elements in the following example)

```
ID   Match                               
1   (word1,,,)                           
2   (word2,,,),(word1)
3   (word2,,,),(word1),(word3,,,)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest use `str` indexer, if not match because value not exist it return `NaN`:

```
#if need slect first tuple
df['new'] = df['Match'].str[0]

#if need select second tuple and first element of tuple
df['new'] = df['Match'].str[1].str[0]
```

**Sample**:

```
a = [[('word1','','','')], 
      [('word2','','',''),('word1', )], 
      [('word2','','',''),('word1', ),('word3','','','')]]

df = pd.DataFrame({'ID':[1,2,3], 'Match':a})

df['new1'] = df['Match'].str[0]
df['new2'] = df['Match'].str[1].str[0]
print (df)

   ID                                     Match           new1   new2
0   1                           [(word1, , , )]  (word1, , , )    NaN
1   2                 [(word2, , , ), (word1,)]  (word2, , , )  word1
2   3  [(word2, , , ), (word1,), (word3, , , )]  (word2, , , )  word1
```

EDIT:

If values are strings use `ast.literal_eval`:

```
import ast

df['Match'] = df['Match'].astype(str)

df['Match'] = df['Match'].apply(ast.literal_eval)
df['new2'] = df['Match'].str[0]
print (df)

   ID                                     Match           new2
0   1                           [(word1, , , )]  (word1, , , )
1   2                 [(word2, , , ), (word1,)]  (word2, , , )
2   3  [(word2, , , ), (word1,), (word3, , , )]  (word2, , , )
```

Comment: thanks, str[0] returns the first character and not the word. what's the problem in your opinion?

Comment: @MostafaAlishahi - Problem is there are strings, not tuples or lists.

Comment: @MostafaAlishahi - hmm, `literal_eval` should help, check edited answer.

Answer (score 0):

Leveraging the above answer, my problem is that I also had a column with a list.

if your table looks something like

Idx    Words
1      ['word1', 'word2']
2      ['word2', 'word3', 'word4']

and you want all the rows where the word "word2" exists

```
    df_result = df_words[ df_words['Words'].str[0] == 'word1']
```